# import to eclipse from android developer tools

Tags: android, eclipse

please help.

When I copy project folder and past for eclipse, don't work it.

what is a tools I can use for export android app from android developer tools  for android eclipse?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What happened when you tried it? Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean "Android Studio" instead of ADT, so, I tried to do that also few weeks ago, but I have no good results, so I did this.

1. I created a new Android project in Eclipse with the same name of the original project
2. Then i created the same packages like the original project
3. Then I copied all the .java files (sources) fkeeping the same structure
4. Finally I added the media elements and the libraries.
5. Hopping it to work, I pressed the Build button and Vualá!!

You can import from Eclipse to Android Studio but I haven't found a better way to do the inverse opperation.

Hope this helps you